# Dired show specific files in default omit-mode

Tags: dired

I'm omitting certain files in dired mode using this hook:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (dired-omit-mode 1)))
```

Is it possible for me to display parent directory `..` in the omit-mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `dired-omit-files` variable controls this. (Note that <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `dired-omit-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells you this.)

I had the same requirement because, although I prefer to use `dired-jump` when I want to open an *additional* dired buffer for the parent directory, I regularly use <kbd>a</kbd> on the `..` entry to *replace* the original dired buffer with its parent.

I'm also including the advice I wrote to revert (buffer-locally) this behaviour automatically when inserting subdirectory contents, because I realised I never want the `..` entry in those listings.

```
;; Do not omit .. in dired -- it's useful...
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.?#\\|^\\.$")
;; ...except when we are inserting sub-directories,
;; as it just makes things messy in those cases.
(defadvice dired-insert-subdir (before my-dired-omit-parents)
  "Omit parent .. directories if inserting subdirectories."
  (setq-local dired-omit-files "^\\.?#\\|^\\.$\\|^\\.\\.$"))
(ad-activate 'dired-insert-subdir)
```

That advice does mean that if you refresh the entire buffer after inserting a sub-directory, you once again lose the top-most `..` entry. In practice I find this isn't a problem for me, because inserting subdirectories typically means I'm building dired contents that I want to keep around for a while, and therefore I'm unlikely to want to replace that buffer with a different one.

---

**Edit:** This Q&A did make me question whether what I really wanted was a convenient way to tell `dired-jump` to kill the buffer of origin, given that navigating to the `..` entry is sometimes annoying. Here's some code to do that.

```
(defun my-dired-jump (arg)
  "Like `dired-jump', but a single (C-u) prefix arg means \"replace the
current buffer with the target dired buffer\" (i.e. kill the original
buffer). A double (C-u C-u) prefix argument triggers the normal prefix
argument behaviour of `dired-jump'."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond
   ((equal arg '(4))
    (let ((origin (current-buffer))
          (current-prefix-arg nil))
      (call-interactively 'dired-jump)
      (kill-buffer origin)))
   ((equal arg '(16))
    (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
      (call-interactively 'dired-jump)))
   (t
    (call-interactively 'dired-jump))))

(eval-after-load 'dired-x
  '(global-set-key [remap dired-jump] 'my-dired-jump))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use options `dired-omit-files` (mentioned by @phils) and `dired-omit-extensions` to control what gets omitted by default.  You can of course also bind these variables in commands you write. As @phils also mentioned, use `C-h f dired-omit-mode` as your starting point for information about omitting entries in Dired.

You can also bookmark Dired buffers that you use frequently. If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then Dired bookmarks record the current omit settings (and markings and subdir insertions etc.).  That gives you a quick way to "jump" to a Dired buffer with particular omit settings.